# Maven Profile Variable web project not working

Tags: maven, variables, inheritance, classification, profile

I´ve got a modular maven project that contains 3 modules. In one of those (WEB), the profile variable is not being recognized as an environment variable, but it takes que real name of it, as shown below:

```
<Principal POM> 
    <Module App-core>
    <Module ejb>    
    <Module web>
```

At the principal POM, there are 3 profiles thas have the same profile propertie with distinct values:

```
<profile1>
    <environment>value1</environment>

<profile2>
    <environment>value2</environment>

<profile3>
    <environment>value3</environment>
```

That variable is used as classifier variable for dependencies, as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <classifier>${environment}</classifier>
</dependency>
```

At maven compile phase, only at Web Project, it doen´t change the variable name with the variable value.

Any help?

Comment: How are you enabling the profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue.

I've replicated the dependencies into profiles. I had multiples dependencies

This is the code to the profile1

```
<profile>
    <id>profile1</id>
<properties>
<environment>value1</environment>
</properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <classifier>${environment}</classifier>
    </dependency>
</profile>
```

This is the code to the profiles2

```
<profile>
    <id>profile2</id>
<properties>
<environment>value2</environment>
</properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <classifier>${environment}</classifier>
    </dependency>
</profile>
```

And this the code is to the profile3

```
<profile>
    <id>profile3</id>
<properties>
<environment>value3</environment>
</properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <classifier>${environment}</classifier>
    </dependency>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags profile1 profile2 profile3 don't enable the replacing property. To do this you have change your parent pom in this way

```
    <project>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile1</id>
                <properties>
                    <environment>value1</environment>   
                </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>profile2</id>
                <properties>
                    <environment>value2</environment>   
                </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>profile3</id>
                <properties>
                    <environment>value2</environment>   
                </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Now you have to run **mvn install -P profile1 yourProjectName**

Comment: I resolved the issue. Your example not working. Thanks